# Is there a way to subset txt data in unix?

Tags: unix, subset, conditional-formatting

I have a txt file that looks like this [Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTNra.png)

I would like to select rows with the "score" column greater than 100. Then removing everything else except for the "Sequence" and "Description" columns. My goal is to obtain a file that looks like this [After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lU8q1.png).

The problem is that the file is not in a tabular format, I can't really select "column", so I am not sure how to proceed.

I tried to do this by deleting the first 15 rows and then finish the rest using excel's "txt to column" conversion tool. But I am looking for an automated way using unix, in case I have more files coming up.

I should have mentioned that there is a line, below which I'd also like to get rid of,[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Om0ID.jpg),

So I tried the following code to remove all lines below the line containing "inclusion threshold" first.

```
sed -n '/inclusion threshold/q;p' file
```

Then use the code that Mr.@Raman Sailopal mentioned

```
awk 'NR>15 && $2>99 { printf $9"\t"$10"\n" } ' file
```

Is there anyway to combine the sed and awk command together, or achieve the same goal with just one function?

Thank you!

Comment: Please, post a proper testable sample, do not post images of data, that's useless - unless you want vague answers, such as: Use GNU awk, look into `NR` and `FIELDWIDTHS`.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk 'NR>15 && $2>100 { printf $9"\t"$10"\n" } ' file
```

Using awk, when the line number (NR) is greater than 15, check that the second space delimited field is less than 100 and if it is, print the the 9th and 10th space delimited fields separated by a tab.

Comment: Thank you Mr.Sailopal, this is really helpful! However, between column 9 and 10 are two space characters instead of a tab, how should I replace the \t with two space characters?

Comment: Change "\t" to "  "